# Searchhits Aggregationcontainer doesn't contain method anymore

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I currently have the problem of having updated from an older spring-data-elasticsearch version to version **4.4.18**. Unfortunately, I am still new to elastic search and am now wondering how I can solve the following problem.

Now, the problem here, is all documentation I've gone through so far suggests me to implement searchHits.getAggregations().get("distinct_projects"), but that's not available in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.18, which we're using. According to the [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.2-4.3.breaking-changes),

> The SearchHitsclass does not contain the
> org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations anymore. Instead it
> now contains an instance of the
> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AggregationsContainer
> class

I would be very happy for any kind of constructive feedback. :)

```
public static Set<Integer> getAggregations(SearchHits<ElasticSearchArticleDto> search, String aggregation)
  {
    Set<Integer> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    if (search.getAggregations() != null && search.getAggregations().get(aggregation) != null)
    {
      ((ParsedLongTerms) search.getAggregations().get(aggregation)).getBuckets()
        .forEach(bucket -> result.add(bucket.getKeyAsNumber().intValue()));
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.x: How to get Aggregations from SearchHits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280992/spring-data-elasticsearch-4-4-x-how-to-get-aggregations-from-searchhits)

Comment: No, i tried it already but it wasn't working for me. Isn't there a easier solution as a custom json mapper?

Comment: No; it's not feasable to try to parse this independent of the client in Spring Data Elasticsearch (there is spring-data-opensearch which has it's own client as well). There are almost 100 classes in the Elasticsearch package for aggregations (the last time I checked), and just from the response it's almost impossible to know what to use without analysing the query - and the query itself must be written using Elasticsearch's classes. When parsing a response, the query is not available.