# AggregationContainer .get missing in spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4.x

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

does anyone have an idea how I can use this aggregation in spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4.x, as the .get(String) method has disappeared from the AggregationContainer? Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to this problem yet. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280992/spring-data-elasticsearch-4-4-x-how-to-get-aggregations-from-searchhits) solution did not work, because my used library (import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchAggregations;
) does not have the aggregationsAsMap() method either.

Would be thankful for any solution.

```
public static Set<ElasticSearchArticleDto> getAggregations(SearchHits<ElasticSearchArticleDto> search, String aggregation) {
    Set<Integer> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    if (search.getAggregations() != null && search.getAggregations().get(aggregation) != null) {
      ((ParsedLongTerms) search.getAggregations().get(aggregation)).getBuckets()
        .forEach(bucket -> result.add(bucket.getKeyAsNumber().intValue()));
    }
  }
```